# Where can I find answers to questions in the book "Paul Wilmott Introduces Quantitative Finance"?

Tags: quantitative

I'm currently answering the exercises at the back of every chapter of the book **"Paul Wilmott Introduces Quantitative Finance"** and would like to compare my answers to the correct ones.  Tried looking at the back of the book but there are no answers. Appreciate if someone can direct me to where I can find the correct answers.  Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I gave you the link to the solutions below - if this answers your question it would be great if you could upvote and accept the answer - Thank you :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can find the answers here:
http://www.wiley.com/legacy/wileychi/pwiqf2/degree.html

Answer (score 2):

As close to a definitive no as you can get:

```
From wcoetzee@wiley.com Wed Nov  5 07:44:32 2014
Date: Wed, 5 Nov 2014 14:44:17 +0000
From: "Coetzee, Werner - London" 
To: "paul@wilmott.com" , Barry Carter 
Subject: RE: Answer key to your books?

    [ The following text is in the "utf-8" character set. ]
    [ Your display is set for the "ISO-8859-1" character set.  ]
    [ Some characters may be displayed incorrectly. ]

Hi Barry,

No, unfortunately there isn't a solutions manual (or answers to the end of chapter 
exercises and questions) for 'Paul Wilmott Introduces Quantitative Finance 2e' (only a
CD which is packaged with the book that features additional spreadsheets/workbooks) nor 
for 'Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance' box set. 

Kind Regards,

Werner


-----Original Message-----
From: Paul Wilmott [mailto:paul@wilmott.com] 
Sent: 05 November 2014 14:24
To: Barry Carter; Coetzee, Werner - London
Subject: Re: Answer key to your books?

W,

Can you help Barry? Is there a solutions manual?

P


> On 5 Nov 2014, at 13:38, Barry Carter  wrote:
>
> How do I show that I'm a lecturer? People tell me I lecture them all the time ;)
>
>> On Mon, 3 Nov 2014, Paul Wilmott wrote:
>>
>> Date: Mon, 3 Nov 2014 20:34:30 +0000
>> From: Paul Wilmott 
>> To: Barry Carter 
>> Subject: Re: Answer key to your books?
>> Only for lecturers!
>>
>> P
>>
>>
>>> On 3 Nov 2014, at 18:53, Barry Carter  wrote:
>>>
>>> Do you offer/have answer keys to the quesions asked in your textbooks?
>


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
John Wiley & Sons Limited is a private limited company registered in England with registered number 641132.
Registered office address: The Atrium, Southern Gate, Chichester, West Sussex, United Kingdom. PO19 8SQ.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Makes me wonder if someone creates a "solution-manual" tag ...